# Turbo C not working in my laptop

Tags: c

I just bought a Dell laptop and Windows 8.1 Pro is installed on it. I want to run Turbo C on my laptop (x64 build).  When I install and run a program in Turbo C it shows output only once then my cursor stops working. I try to click on Run or compile in turbo c menu nothing happens. It appears like my click is not affecting anything. I have tried Windows 7 also and the same thing is happening. And I have tried all the versions of Turbo C.

Comment: How about the 'not Turbo C' version?

Comment: you say x64 build... I assume you mean your laptop is a 64 bit laptop, which pretty much would seem to answer the question assuming you mean Turbo C, the classic tool from the 90's which is a 16 bit app and therefore probably won't work under Windows 7/8 on 64 bit

Comment: actually, a quick google shows I'm probably wrong and you did mean Turbo C for Windows which is in fact supposed to work on Windows 8.  Yowsers...

Comment: There is 32-bit Turbo C, but nobody knows how it survived the K-T event.

Comment: okay You mean to say that it wont work in my laptop. But i am confused it installed properly and i run a " hello world" program. it showed the output but after the that i wasnt be able to run it again. its is happening with all the versions i install, this same thing.

Comment: wHat i am suppose to do now?? please tell

Comment: Learn C and C++ on latest available compilers. For windows you can go for MinGW GCC or Microsoft Visual C++. Even if your school/college is using TurboC or BorlandC suggest them to switch to newer version, as its decade old and full of bugs and non-standard stuff. AT SO don't expect somebody answering TurboC question. SO community hates this.

Comment: Yes , in my college they are still using Turbo c or Older version compilers. I agree with you i should switch to new Compilers.

Comment: Somehow i want to run C compiler in my laptop. And i am helpless to do so.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're trying to run a program from within Turbo C, and when you do it locks up?  Is it just locking up the Turbo C application, or the whole system?  Are you sure there isn't a problem in the program you are trying to run (such as an infinite loop)?  Have you tried to run it outside of Turbo C?

Comment: Only My Turbo c Lock up And i can only use my keyboard just to write and i have run a simple "hello world" program to check all the versions.@JohnBode

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the 64 bit version of Turbo C if you haven't already. If that isn't an option, you might be able to get it to work by running in compatibility mode.

Right click the icon -> Properties -> Compatibility then select Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry. Just press
`Alt+Space` and then press enter.
With this we are giving repaint desktop command, which is available in drop down menu left to file menu.

Answer (score 0):

Install dosbox from [here](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) and then follow the tutorial [here](http://blog.windows8downloads.com/2013/02/how-to-install-and-start-turbo-c-on-windows-8-x32-x64/)

DOSBox can run old MS-DOS software on modern computers which would not work otherwise, because of incompatibilities between the older software and modern hardware and operating systems.
Turbo C is a 16 bit software,you are trying it on a 64 bit OS

Comment: Then i suggest you to go for MS Visual C++

Comment: If i use Visual C++. Is there a difference in coding?

Comment: No. Infact  you will love coding on it. You can easily switch over to it and I suggest that you should. Because its an IDE. :)

Comment: @SamDunk, MS Visual C++ doesn't support many features of C99, is not the appropriate compiler for C.

Comment: @AkshitVerma Do you aim using it for educational programming or professional development?

Comment: @AkshitVerma Then don't think much,just install Visual Studio and have a good coding time :)